# AS3 limit of Soundchannel?

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, simultaneous

i'm developing an bullet hell arena shooter game,the game will have lots of enemies and bullets so it needs a lot of sound effects play at the same time. I only use one soundChannel to handle all sound effects, and the problem is...sometimes,certain sound doesn't play, is there a limit for sound playing in SoundChannel?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This library http://joeberkovitz.com/blog/2009/05/15/standingwave-open-source-as3-audio/. Can mix all ur sounds. Simple to use and sounds much better then flash sound player.

Answer (score 0):

yes, i believe there is a limit.
lots of little gun sound effects and multiple explosions at once can be too much sometimes.

If I read the docs correctly, I think each sound should have it's own SoundChannel.

Then you manage all the sounds using the SoundMixer class.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundMixer.html

With this class you can also set up a sound buffer so that all the effects should play at the right time.